# Unable to implicitly convert value from enum even though the underlying type is specified

Tags: c#, .net, enums

In the following code sample I define an enum and specify its underlying type as byte. I then attempt to assign to a byte value and switch on the enum's values but I get an error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'CmdlnFlags' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

The code:

```
using System;

public enum CmdlnFlags: byte {
    ValA = (byte)'a',
    ValB = (byte)'b',
}

public class Sample {
    public static void Main() {
        byte switchByte = CmdlnFlags.ValB;
        switch (switchByte) {
            case CmdlnFlags.ValA: Console.WriteLine('A'); break;
            case CmdlnFlags.ValB: Console.WriteLine('B'); break;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

It's easy enough to fix, just cast to byte, but why do I have to cast if the underlying type is specified for the enum? What's the point of specifying an underlying type if you have to cast anyway?

If I cast, everything works. Example:

```
        byte switchByte = (byte)CmdlnFlags.ValB;
        switch (switchByte) {
            case (byte)CmdlnFlags.ValA: Console.WriteLine('A'); break;
            case (byte)CmdlnFlags.ValB: Console.WriteLine('B'); break;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to cast to make sure that's really what you mean to do. It's a type safety feature.

You should think of the enum as being a distinct type from its underlying type - and from other enums with the same underlying type. They're sufficiently different that if you want to use one as another, you need to cast.

It can occasionally be a pain, but ultimately it's a good thing.

Why are you casting before the switch anyway though? Just switch on the actual enum values:

```
CmdlnFlags switchFlag = CmdlnFlags.ValB;
switch (switchFlag) {
    case CmdlnFlags.ValA: Console.WriteLine('A'); break;
    case CmdlnFlags.ValB: Console.WriteLine('B'); break;
}
```

Here, you don't *really* want to treat the flag as a byte - you want to treat it as a flag and switch on it. So that's exactly what you should do.

Comment: So from a view outside of the declaration scope, an enum has no specific type. You must always cast an enumeration except when it's an plain old integer enum. Is this correct?

Comment: @Sergio: No, an enum is a distinct type. What do you mean by "outside of the declaration scope" exactly?

Comment: The code snippet is just something I whipped up in Snippet Compiler to quickly show some scenarios. +1 Great point about thinking of enums as separate types. Though I still don't understand the point of specifying an underlying type if you have to handle it with kid gloves later anyway?

Comment: @Paul: Think of it as like a struct with a single field of the underlying type. It's not the same as the underlying type, but that decides what it can store.

Comment: @Jon: I mean, if I were to read the code I *know* it's a byte enum, but when calling it in code I **must** cast it to the correct type. The compiler doesn't infer the underlying type. That was my question.

Comment: @Sergio: Yes, you must cast it because it's a different type, and you should tell the compiler that's really what you want to do. It's not something you should be doing often.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks, that makes perfect sense. Funny/ironic: I got into this scenario whilst refactoring some constant values and organizing them into an enum. Had I coded the enum right away the question would have never come up.

Comment: "It can occasionally be a pain, but ultimately it's a good thing." Wrong.

Comment: @Joshua: Well a single word assertion certainly isn't going to persuade me. Are you saying you'd want implicit conversions between enums and integer types, and other enums? I'd far rather have type safety to avoid accidentally using the wrong kind of enum...

Comment: Our code is littered with if (property == (byte)EnumName.EnumValue) or the equivalent in a switch.

Comment: @Joshua: Maybe the property should be the enum type rather than `byte` then? I think it's entirely reasonable for a comparison between two values of different types to require an explicit conversion - and if you find yourself doing that a lot, it's *usually* a sign that something is wrong. Obviously I can't tell for sure without seeing your code, but if your code is *littered* with that, it does sound like something's not right.

Comment: About half the time that properties acts like enums, and about half the time they just don't. The debate almost went the other way of tearing out the enum altogether and just make constants. There are two such properties, but they're right in the heart of everything.

Comment: @Joshua: Why not have two properties, both exposing the same data, but one with a cast either to or from the enum type? Then you'd have a single per property rather than it "littering" your codebase.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, such casts are unnecessary. Rather than use a variable of type `byte` to control the switch, just create a variable of type `CmdlnFlags`.

```
    CmdlnFlags switchValue = CmdlnFlags.ValB;
    switch (switchValue) {
         case CmdlnFlags.ValA: Console.WriteLine('A'); break;
         case CmdlnFlags.ValB: Console.WriteLine('B'); break;
     }
```

The casts are required to encourage a correct program design. You will typically not want to use an enum as a numeric value.