# Enums casting to a byte

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Am using EntityFramework and have a LinkStatusID column which is a tinyint, which gets generated into a byte in C#.

```
public enum LinkStatus
{
    Added = 0,
    Deleted = 1
}
```

however this gives:

```
a.LinkStatusID = (byte)Enums.LinkStatus.Deleted;
```

is there a more elegant way to structure this?

EDIT2 for LastCoder:

```
public enum LinkStatus : byte
{
    Added = 0,
    Deleted = 1
}

    var blah = Enums.LinkStatus.Added;
    var ty = blah.GetType();

    var blah2 = (byte)Enums.LinkStatus.Added;
    var ty2 = blah2.GetType();
```

This doesn't work (as I expected) however the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625873/unable-to-implicitly-convert-value-from-enum-even-though-the-underlying-type-is) explains why.

EDIT3:
EF isn't the only way this sln gets to the DB, so I'm keen to keep the Enums explicit in the code.  Thanks for EF5 Enum suggestions!

Comment: EF5 has native enum support.

Answer (score 4):

```
public enum LinkStatus : byte
```

Will avoid the explicit cast.

Comment: Thanks - however see above for code which didn't quite work as I expected... unless I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

A static class can be used as a workaround

```
public static class LinkStatus 
{
    public static byte 
        Added = 0, 
        Deleted = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the native enum support, like SLaks mentioned above (Tutorial [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576.aspx)). If you don't want to do that, you can do something else that I found for before EF supported it:

```
public int CountryInt{get;set;}
public Countries Country
        {
            get { return (Countries) this.CountryInt; }
            set { this.CountryInt = (int) value; }
        }
```

Using this, then, allows you to just set the Country variable, and have it automatically go to the DB as the correct int value.